# Deploy Django SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django, deployment, secret-key

I need some help.

settings.py:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'fpod51u&htaw-99=vl6c8vdqlt$yydvlr)p&aob5f9pd2t9p+8'
```

but returns error as follows:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting
>   must not be empty.

whats happens?

Comment: do you have development or any other config other than base config?

Comment: a full project: https://github.com/Gabrielgqa/gameofprojects

Comment: Where are you deploying it, and how?

Comment: Try deleting all .pyc from project with this command `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Or set this environment variable: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='gameofprojects.settings'`

Comment: Afterall, `SECRET_KEY` is no more secret

Comment: And first and foremost, what did you do to trigger it? We all assume you ran `python manage.py check`, but did you really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens when your settings are not being loaded (or found) by Django. Make sure your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` [environment variable is set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) (correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an external file named "key.py" and add only your secret key.

After that import the file in settings.py like:

> from yourapp.key import *

Comment: All that does it add more CPU cycles.

Comment: you need to keep the SECRET_KEY secret.... i can deploy it in your settings.py...

Comment: If it doesn't show up in hardcoded in settings.py what makes you think importing an external file is going to make a difference?